AdressSanitizer not catching a memory leak
The following program contains a memory leak:
#include <new>
#include <memory>

template <class T> class AlignedStorage {
    union {
        T t;
    };
public:
    AlignedStorage() {}
    ~AlignedStorage() {}
    T* data() {
        return &t;
    }
};

int main() {
    using T = std::unique_ptr<int>;
    AlignedStorage<T> s;
    new (s.data()) T(new int(42));
}

If I compile it with g++ -O0 -g file.cpp and run the resulting program through valgrind it will tell me:
LEAK SUMMARY:
definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

However, if I compile the program with g++ -O0 -g -fsanitize=address file.c and then run the resulting binary, there is no error message from AdressSanitizer. Is this expected or is it a bug in AdressSanitizer? Does AdressSanitizer not detect all memory leaks? If so, which memory leaks exactly will AdressSanitizer detect?

Your question makes me wonder : Is this even defined behavior? Doing a placement new on an inactive member of a union I mean (I can't find if that consitutes a write). So if anybody knows I'd be happy to learn. If it is UB... all bets are of. Also for sanitizers. (Have you tried building with ubsanitizer option yet?)

@PepijnKramer There is a similar example Stroustrup's C++11 FAQ that uses placement new on a union member.

Ok, I just never came accross this in my 30+ years of C++ ;)

@PepijnKramer I believe this is how std::optional and std::variant are implemented.

@eyelash Standard library implementations can do whatever they want without it being UB.

Ecuuse me, where is a leak here? code could be simpler, but thing is that destructor off smark pointer never is called. You essentally tricked  run-time to cause a leak, static analizers can't find that

@Swift-FridayPie new int(42). And ASan  isn’t a static analyser (but it’s also not a leak finder — but Valgrind is).

@KonradRudolph it leaked to to (in)action of run-time library afterde-initialization of program, in-compiler checks like -fsanitize are not meant to to ever detect it.

@Swift-FridayPie See the rest of my comment. And ASan is a red herring anyway, OP is running Valgrind, which is designed to find memory leaks.

@KonradRudolph AdressSanitizer contains LeakSanitizer which is supposed to find memory leaks.

@eyelash Ah, interesting. I thought it was separate (via -fsanitize=leak). Either way, there is a leak, and it should be found.

@eyelash But not on all platforms: on Apple Clang at least Address sanitizer does not contain LeakSanitizer

@KonradRudolph and valgrind is correct  here for case of gcc (GNU union behaviour - gcc retains it even with /std::c++**): neither T's constructor nor destructor are called.

@Swift-FridayPie The constructor is completely irrelevant (except, well, to make this not UB): the point is that the code is clearly calling new int(42), thereby allocating (and subsequently leaking) memory.

@KonradRudolph isn't it std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42))? we allocating that with placement-new, The non-UB thing here would be explicitly  calling s.data()->~T(); Formally placement new is write and we had cretaed the object. But there is no mechanism to deallocate it via RAII.

@prapin I'm running this with GCC on Linux where AdressSanitizer does contain LeakSanitizer.

@Swift-FridayPie Oh I completely missed the unique_ptr part.

yeah, I think what happens here is that approach which prevents false positives (a bane of some leak-detecing libraries), the leak detection summary happens too early and cannot discern if some subobject had not been deleted by run-time because of implicitly-deleted destructor. A flaw.

This is strange: https://godbolt.org/z/v3v361ej1

The way that LSan works pointers on the stack of main may still be considered reachable at the end of the program execution (which is the only point where LSan looks for leaked memory). When you play around with optimization and other sanitizer options, you will affect whether or not the pointer returned by new will be placed somewhere on main's stack and whether or not they will be overwritten before the leak detection, changing this determination.
Move the code into a function (that is not inlined) and it seems to usually work as expected, as long as the function isn't inlined at least. (https://godbolt.org/z/bPvedsKEz):
void f() {
    using T = std::unique_ptr<int>;
    AlignedStorage<T> s;
    new (s.data()) T(new int(42));
}

int main() {
    f();
}

More robust seems to be to add an unused array of some large enough size (don't know how much) to main.
The design of LSan is described here. You can find multiple reports/explanations of issues detecting leaks in main's frame on the Github page, e.g. this one.
In general, the way that LSan works is not guaranteed to find leaks.

Even with the extra function, if I change it from -fsanitize=address to -fsanitize=address,undefined it will report no error again.

@eyelash As mentioned in the linked issue, it could be that more than just main's frame will overlap incorrectly. I don't know how much of the stack is potentially an issue, but you could add an unused array to main of sufficient size, so that whatever pointers f writes to the stack are far enough away from the region that LSan operates in.
